# How sort date in array form oldest to newest php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, date

I have a problem.
I can't sort date in array from oldest to newest ;/
My array:

```
$arr = array('2013-02-01','2000-02-01','2016-02-17','0000-00-00','0000-00-00','0000-00-00');
```

i want output

```
array(
[0] => '2000-02-01',
[1] => '2013-02-01',
[2] => '2016-02-01',
[3] => '0000-00-00',
[4] => '0000-00-00',
[5] => '0000-00-00',
)
```

i use own function callback in usort, but this not work ;/

```
function sortDate($a, $b)
{
    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    } elseif($a == '0000-00-00') {
        return 1;
    }

    return strtotime($a) < strtotime($b) ? 1 : -1;
}
```

someone has an idea for a solution?

Comment: Just plain `sort` would do it in this case...

Comment: If a<b, you want -1, not 1. Older dates have lower values. Also, you don't need to strtotime since the string comparison of YYYY-MM-DD works just fine.

Comment: I used the function sort , but it did not help. You can show my code on phpfiddle: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/yfn3-ugmt

Comment: @devbochenek I think I got it

Answer (score 1):

The best sort is:

```
usort($childs, function ($a, $b) {
            if ($a == '0000-00-00')
                return 1;

            if ($b == '0000-00-00')
                return -1;

            if ($a == $b)
                return 0;

            return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I remove all the zero values from the array, then sort it as needed, and then add zero values back:

```
$arr = array('2013-02-01','2000-02-01','2016-02-17','0000-00-00','0000-00-00','0000-00-00');
$count = count($arr);

$arr = array_filter($arr, function($v) {
    if($v == '0000-00-00') {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH);

$count -= count($arr);

sort($arr);

$arr = array_merge($arr, array_fill(0, $count, '0000-00-00'));

print_r($arr);
```

This sorts your array as following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2000-02-01
    [1] => 2013-02-01
    [2] => 2016-02-17
    [3] => 0000-00-00
    [4] => 0000-00-00
    [5] => 0000-00-00
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give the result you want tested in PHP versions 5.3.22 - 5.6.18, but there has been changes in PHP 7 that affect the usort function:

```
$arr = array('2013-02-01','2000-02-01','2016-02-17','0000-00-00','0000-00-00','0000-00-00');

sort( $arr );
usort( $arr, function( $a, $b )
{
    if ( $a === $b ) return 0;
    if ( strpos( $b, '0000' ) !== false ) return -1;
    return ( $a < $b ) ? -1 : 1;
});
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2000-02-01
    [1] => 2013-02-01
    [2] => 2016-02-17
    [3] => 0000-00-00
    [4] => 0000-00-00
    [5] => 0000-00-00
)
```

Test:

https://3v4l.org/0Tvlm

Answer (score -1):

You have the date comparison backwards. You have:

```
return strtotime($a) < strtotime($b) ? 1 : -1;
```

You want:

```
return strtotime($a) < strtotime($b) ? -1 : 1;
```

You can use:

```
return $a < $b ? -1 : 1;
```

Comment: thanks for pointing out my answer was invalid, it was not obvious from the question. But your answer gives me `Array ( [0] => 0000-00-00 [1] => 2000-02-01 [2] => 2013-02-01 [3] => 0000-00-00 [4] => 2016-02-17 [5] => 0000-00-00)` in the end

Comment: Thanks, but it did not help :( I have the same answer, but I want to fix it to work correctly